# What is the standard method to keep track of the latest Cumulative updates for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

What resources are good for keeping track of cumulative updates for SQL Server? I noticed that Windows update does provide a service for SQL Server.

Comment: I don't think cumulative updates appear on Microsoft Update.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

["SQL Server Version Database](http://www.sqlsecurity.com/FAQs/SQLServerVersionDatabase/tabid/63/Default.aspx)" on sqlsecurity.com (worth a look at the site anyway)

Edit: It's been around for years and I've used since SQL 2000 SP3...

Comment: Wow, that's nice.  And to know when it changes, you can use http://www.WatchThatPage.com.  It's got a crappy UI, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

I like the Microsoft SQL Server Release Services blog - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlreleaseservices/. It's updated very quickly once there is a new release and has links to the relevant KB articles too.

Definitely worth adding to your RSS.

Answer (score 1):

There is a blogspot site that seems to be pretty up to date at http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/ which has a chart of SQL server updates for all versions.

Comment: I like that site. Also, Microsoft maintains various KB articles, such as: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/960598